# how to write mongodb find with and operator using gretter then less then query in php

Tags: php, mongodb

Can any one write below query in php formate for execute using php.

db.MSISDN_RANG.find( {$and:[ {msisdn_start_range:{$lt:919967288367}}, {msisdn_end_range:{$gt:919967288367}} ]} ).pretty()

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Just change `dbName` and `collectionName`

```
     <?php
        $connection = new MongoClient(sprintf('mongodb://%s:%d/%s', '127.0.0.1', '27017', 'dbName'));    
        $db = $connection->selectDB('dbName');
        $table = $db->selectCollection('collectionName');
        $cursor = $table->find( 
                            array(                       
                                    'msisdn_start_range' => array('$lt' => 919967288367 ),  
                                    'msisdn_end_range' => array('$gt' => 919967288367 )                                         
                               )
                           );
        $cursor = iterator_to_array($cursor);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($cursor);
```